# Mongoose - Excluding fields from returned object on .save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

When I save a new user to my app's database, I need to return a user object back to the client, but there are certain fields in the user object I want excluded so the client doesn't receive them.

Currently I'm saving the document, then finding that document in the collection again, excluding some fields, then sending that.

Is it possible to exclude the fields on .save instead, saving another trip back to the database?

```
...

function hashing(err, hash) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    newUser.password = hash;
    newUser.save(saveUser);
}

function saveUser(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    User.findOne({ username: user.username },
    '-purchased -following -songs')
    .exec(findAndSendUser);
}

function findAndSendUser(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }

    res.send({
        success: true,
        user: user
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just use [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) to omit certain fields from the user

```
_ = require('underscore');

...

function saveUser(err, user) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    }
    findAndSendUser(err, _.omit(user.toJSON(), 'purchased', 'following', 'songs'));
}
```

Comment: I've tried doing this before but for whatever reason, if you run an object returned from a .save or a .findOne for example through Underscore, it won't change that object at all.

`_.omit(user, ['purchased', 'following', 'songs']);` still includes the same properties I've tried to omit.

Comment: It doesn't mutate the object, but returns an object with the omitted fields. It's also possible that you need to call toJSON() on the model before invoking `omit`. See my edit

Comment: That seems to work a lot better. Thanking you kindly.

Comment: Cheers! Mongoose returns a `Document` from queries by default, which, while they quack like objects don't quite have the same behavior as objects. You can also add `lean()` to your query to have it return plain old javascript objects, and then you wouldn't need to `toJSON` -- `lean` is also slightly faster I'm told and generally good practice if you don't need mongoose documents. You can read about it here http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean

Comment: Ah yes! +1 for this ^.

Been looking for something like lean() for a while now, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```js
let user = await UserModel.create({
  email: "example@example.com",
  password: "example"
});

user = user.toObject();

delete user.password;

console.log(user);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "_id": "5dd3fb12b40da214026e0658",
  "email": "example@example.com"
}
```